# Determine data types in Orbeon form submission data

Tags: forms, orbeon, xforms, formbuilder

Im am using the `send` button (formally `workflow-send`) to submit the data entered in an Orbeon form. Afterwards, I send this data to a custom servlet to parse this data and to send the values to a process engine.

The problem is that in the submission xml data generated by Orbeon, there is no information about the datatypes. Lets say I have an Orbeon form with a textfield, a textarea and a date field. The generated submission xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xxf:id="0f81046cee210b5b64db5706b6fe79f986fb539b">                    
  <section-1 xxf:id="e7d2bb4ac261e77159fc236e7fd922c3540756f8">                        
     <approver xxf:id="6e3c7a6f088fb15e633358f17f9a495cbbb0191f">Person 1</approver>                        
     <duedate xxf:id="b28aedbc6f2d4bd8872a48c06d2eed65cc062498">2014-11-20</duedate>                        
     <comments xxf:id="0f931e5351491df185889d62274e1d706c901293">This is a test comment</comments>                    
  </section-1> 
</form>
```

Since I will have to process different forms with the same servlet, I need to know which data types exist in the corresponding Orbeon form. Is there a way to configure this? Orbeon should also send the data types in the submission xml so that a http service is able to process those data properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this since Orbeon Forms 4.7, with `send(content = "metadata")`. You can find more on this in the documentation for the [`send()` action](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes#send).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to process the form data within one servlet in one request. Therefore, is it also possible to send the content and the Metadata within one xml-structure instead of using two distinct requests for content and metadata?

Comment: For this reason, when you ask for the metadata to be sent, the values for the controls are also in there. For instance, see the `<value>` elements in this example: https://gist.github.com/orbeon/3684806b0a30a9a5ace9. But we've been thinking of ways to send the data + the metadata + the attachments in the same request (e.g. multipart/form-data), but this isn't implemented at this point.

Comment: @BenSchnarr Also, I should add that since 4.7, a new request parameter, `process`, is passed to service, and the value of that request parameter will be the same for all the send() operations executed as part of the same process. So, should you want to send both the data and the metadata, even though this will be done in 2 separate requests, you have a way of knowing which requests correlate using the `process` request parameter.

Comment: @BenSchnarr This is documented on: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes#url-format

Comment: I tried it with send(content = "metadata") in orbeon 4.7 but for an input field, I only see the type="input" tag, but the important datatype="string" tag is still missing. How can I achieve that the datatype-tag is also sent?

Comment: the value-tag is also missung when I use an input-field. Is this normal?

Comment: If there is a schema type, in the metadata document, you should find that information in the `datatype` attribute. Try with something other that a string, as a string doesn't add any constraint. And see https://gist.github.com/orbeon/3684806b0a30a9a5ace9 for an example.

Comment: @BenSchnarr The <value> element was added in 4.7.1; sorry for the confusion, and the doc has now been updated to reflect that. https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Form-Runner-~-Buttons-and-Processes#sending-form-metadata

Comment: I just tried 4.7.1 PE, but still, there are no value-tags for input-controls like text fields and text areas. Only with a boolean checkbox, I can see the selected one as a value-tag. But when I use a textfield, there is no value in the metadata. Is this the normal behaviour? Because I need to get the datatypes AND the user input within the same XML. I hoped to get done with this with 4.7.1

Comment: I also tested your own bookshelf form. It is not working in 4.7.1, no value-tag in there.

Comment: As discussed on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/orbeon/status/540561981518798848), this change should have made it but didn't. Creating new build now.